# How to open a modal Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I'm new an angular js. I'm using the modal and using this tutorial http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QIfjLqr1-4 unfortunatly it dosn't work for me. This is my code:

```
    <div uib-dropdown keyboard-nav>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu positionFix" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">My account</a></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-click="">Notification</a></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:void(0);"   ng-click="logout()">Sign out</a></li>
                </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" >
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                     <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">
                                          <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                                      </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                              </div>
                         </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Angular.js in conjunction with Bootstrap, I would recommend using [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

It covers most of the integration between Angular.js and Bootstrap that you will need. They even provide directives and services for launching Modals.

See the [Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal) section.

Comment: That or the ng-bootstrap modal : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Comment: @Alex Beugnet ng-bootstrap is for Angular, not for AngularJS. I think the author questions for angularjs.

Comment: @MeMeMax That's true, I didn't pay attention. Does that still exist ? :-)